# Navigation Drawer not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I combined navigation drawer with tabs layout. In that tab, the layout is working properly for three tabs but navigation drawer is misbehaving. The navigation drawer icon disappeared, it is opening by sliding by not getting closed by sliding. And also the menus in navigation drawer are not working.

```
                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private View navHeader;
private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
ActionBar actionBar;
//This is our tablayout
private TabLayout tabLayout;

//This is our viewPager
private ViewPager viewPager;

// urls to load navigation header background image
// and profile image
private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

// index to identify current nav menu item
public static int navItemIndex = 0;

// tags used to attach the fragments
private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
private static final String TAG_PHOTOS = "photos";
private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

// toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
private String[] activityTitles;

// flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

  //  fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    // Navigation view header
    navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
    imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
    imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

    // load toolbar titles from string resources
    activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

  /*  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    // load nav menu header data
    loadNavHeader();

    // initializing navigation menu
    setUpNavigationView();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        navItemIndex = 0;
        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
        loadHomeFragment();
    }

     /*
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/


    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Search Bride"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Search Groom"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, positionOffset, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views

        //tabLayout.setOnClickListener();


    });
}


/***
 * Load navigation menu header information
 * like background image, profile image
 * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
 */
private void loadNavHeader() {
    // name, website
    txtName.setText("shubham");
    txtWebsite.setText("shubhamkanugo@gmail.com");

    // loading header background image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
            .crossFade()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

    // Loading profile image
    Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
            .crossFade()
            .thumbnail(0.5f)
            .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(imgProfile);

    // showing dot next to notifications label
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
}

/***
 * Returns respected fragment that user
 * selected from navigation menu
 */
private void loadHomeFragment() {
    // selecting appropriate nav menu item
    selectNavMenu();

    // set toolbar title
    setToolbarTitle();

    // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
    // just close the navigation drawer
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // show or hide the fab button
        //toggleFab();
        return;
    }

    // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
    // when switching between navigation menus
    // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
    // This effect can be seen in GMail app
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            HomeFragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
           // FragmentTransaction replace = fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    };

    // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }

    // show or hide the fab button
  //  toggleFab();

    //Closing drawer on item click
    drawer.closeDrawers();

    // refresh toolbar menu
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

private HomeFragment getHomeFragment() {
    switch (navItemIndex) {
        case 0:
            // home
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            return homeFragment;
        case 1:
            // photos
            PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
            return photosFragment;
        case 2:
            // movies fragment
            MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
            return moviesFragment;
        case 3:
            // notifications fragment
            NotificationFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationFragment();
            return notificationsFragment;

        case 4:
            // settings fragment
            SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
            return settingsFragment;
        default:
            return new HomeFragment();
    }
}

private void setToolbarTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
}

private void selectNavMenu() {
    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
}

private void setUpNavigationView() {
    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_photos:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_movies:
                    navItemIndex = 2;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    navItemIndex = 3;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    navItemIndex = 4;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about_us:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                    // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });


    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    // show menu only when home fragment is selected
    if (navItemIndex == 0) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    }

    // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
    if (navItemIndex == 3) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
    if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



    // user is in notifications fragment
    // and selected 'Clear All'
    if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// show or hide the fab





@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: plz check the xml provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please follow this order for tabs with navigation drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#ffffff">
          <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                android:theme="@style/MainTheme.AppBarOverlay">
                 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/MainTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
             android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
             android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
          <!-- View pager to swipe views -->
           <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
             android:id="@+id/pager"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
         </RelativeLayout>
          <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
      </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks MinnuKaAnae for your help. /\